# Trying to get property of non-object displayed with valid object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and active record and facing a weird issue.

I have the following PHP code:

```
foreach ($list_all->result() as $all_Array){
   $current_r = $all_Array->id_r;
   $get_ongoing_loan_player = $this->get_ongoing_loan_player($current_r);
   $ongoing_loan_info = $get_ongoing_loan_player->row();
   var_dump($ongoing_loan_info);
   $daily_payment_player = $ongoing_loan_info->daily_payment;
   ...
}
```

`get_ongoing_loan_player` looks like this:

```
protected function get_ongoing_loan_player($currentID){
  $this->db->select('daily_payment');
  $this->db->from('game_signed_loans');
  $this->db->where('id_r', $currentID);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query;
}
```

But PHP throws an error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object

The `var_dump` returns the following:

> object(stdClass)#38 (1) { ["daily_payment"]=> string(5) "38670" } NULL

Please note the `NULL` at the end outside the brackets. I haven't been able to find an explanation for this `NULL`.

I have a really similar function just before and it works fine but in that one the `NULL` is not there. I'm pretty sure it's caused by that.

I don't need to load the model as it is on the same page (and I tried it didn't help anyway).

My result is an object and not an array so I can't understand the error message...

Comment: I'm going to guess that the first iteration through the foreach has an object. The second iteration, it's a null, so it throws the error.

Comment: right! didn't think that it was the iteration printing the NULL. Fixed it! Add your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first iteration, `$ongoing_loan_info` is an object, so it prints out and works correctly. In your second iteration, `$ongoing_loan_info` is null, so throws an error. You'll want to make sure that the row exists before trying to get data out of it. This ternary will set the player to 0 if it's null, or you can replace it with whatever you want.

```
$daily_payment_player = $ongoing_loan_info ? $ongoing_loan_info->daily_payment : 0;
```